# 'StringVar' object has no attribute '_report_exception'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I had been working on this piece of code, which is an auto complete entry widget
When I test the program, it seems to output

'StringVar' object has no attribute '_report_exception'

when I type something onto the entry box and press backspace.
I tried to search for a solution of this problem but no one seems to have this output. I heard some people talked about similar problem, where they made StringVar inherit Tk so attribute will exist. Sorry for being a noob but I don't really know how to do it.

Or is it other problem causing this?

If you are looking for StringVar, it's on line 15 only.

```
from tkinter import *
import re


class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, auto_list=[], *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Find out maximum number of words can one suggestion include in autocomplete list
        # This will be used later
        self.auto_list = auto_list
        auto_list = [item.split() for item in auto_list]
        self.max_words = len(max(auto_list, key=len))

        # Get the text from entry when there is changes made to entry
        self.var = self['textvariable'] = StringVar()
        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)

        # Set listbox(suggestion box) to doesn't exist
        self.list_exist = False

        # Binding keys use to control selection
        self.bind('<Return>', self.KeyReturn)
        self.bind('<Tab>', self.KeyTab)

    def KeyReturn(self, event):
        if self.list_exist:
            # Fetch the current select value
            value = self.list.get(self.list_index)

            ## Clear the content of Entry and replace with selected value
            self.delete(0,"end")
            self.insert(0, value)

            # Destroy the list and state that it doesn't exist anymore
            self.list.destroy()
            self.list_exist = False

    def KeyTab(self, event):
        if self.list_exist:
            # Clear the last selection before proceeding
            self.list.selection_clear(self.list_index)


            # Make selection to the next one
            self.list_index += 1

            # list index started from -1 and increment by 1, causes div by 0 error
            try:
                self.list_index = self.list_index%(self.list.size()-1)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                self.list_index = 0

            self.list.selection_set(self.list_index)
            self.list.activate(self.list_index)
            # This special break prevent widget switch when list is there
            return 'break'

        # If list is not there, allow switch by pressing tab
        return 
    def regex_match(self,typed):
        matches = []
        patterns = []

        for words in typed:
            # Make sure it's not spaces made up the typing
            if words.strip != '':
                patterns.append(r'(%s)'%(words))

        # Sort the pattern list according to length of words, from longest to shortest
        patterns.sort(key=len,reverse=True)
        # Compile the patterns and ignore cases
        patterns = [re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE) for pattern in patterns]
        # Matching done from longest pattern to shortest
        for pattern in patterns:
            for phrase in self.auto_list:
                result = pattern.match(phrase)
                if result == None:
                    continue
                else:
                    matches.append(phrase)

        return matches

    def changed(self,name,index,mode):
        # Get all the words already been typed up so far and split into list by space
        words = self.var.get().split()

        # If there is nothing in the entry and list exist, destroy list 
        if words == [] and self.list_exist:
            self.list.destroy()
            self.list_exist = False

        ## There are more code to add here if we don't want to autocomplete only the last phrase in the text field

        # Getting typed words, getting all the possibilities
        typed = []
        for i in range(1,self.max_words):
            # break if max words > what currently typed and when all possibility are obtained, otherwise may cause index out of range
            if i > len(words):
                break
            typed.append(' '.join(words[-i:]))

        # Only proceed matching method if typed list is not empty
        if len(typed) > 0:
            matches = self.regex_match(typed)


        # Manage autocompletion list box

        self.manage_auto(matches)

    def manage_auto(self, matches):
        # if there is no match but list is there, take it out
        if len(matches) == 0 and self.list_exist:
            self.list.destroy()
            self.list_exist = False
        # if there are suggestions but no list, create list and insert matches
        elif len(matches) > 0 and not self.list_exist:
            # Create the listbox for suggestions
            self.list = Listbox(width = self['width'])
            self.list.place(x=self.winfo_x(),y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height())
            self.list_exist = True
            # Insert values
            for match in matches:
                self.list.insert("end",match)
            self.list_index = -1

        elif len(matches) > 0 and self.list_exist:
            # Replace the matches by first deleting all
            self.list.delete(0,"end")
            # Now insert the new matches
            for match in matches:
                self.list.insert("end",match)
            self.list_index = -1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    items = ['Cash and Equivalent', 'Marketable Securities', 'Trade Receivables', 'Bad Debt Allowance', 'Inventory', 'Others Current Asset', 'Tangibles', 'Intangibles', 'Other Intangibles ', 'Deferred Tax Asset', 'Other Non-Current Asset', 'Current Debt', 'Account Payable', 'Provisions', 'Other Current Liability', 'Non-Current Debt', 'Deferred Tax Liability', 'Other Non-Current Liability', 'Ordinary Share Capital', 'Other Capital', 'Retained Earnings', 'Other Reserves', 'Operating Revenue', 'Cost of Sales', 'Selling, General and Administrative Expenses', 'Other Operating Expense', 'Depreciation and Amortization', 'Other Income', 'Other Expense', 'Operating Cash Flow', 'Purchase/Sale of Non-Current Asset', 'Capital Expenditures', 'Other Investment/Acquisition', 'Net Interest Cost', 'Net Debt Issuance(Repayment)', 'Net Share Issuance(Repurchase)', 'Dividends', 'Investment Income', 'Net Interest Expense', 'Tax Expense']


    root = Tk()

    a = AutocompleteEntry(items, root, width = 150)
    b = AutocompleteEntry(items, root, width = 150)
    a.pack()
    b.pack()
    a.focus()


    root.mainloop()
```

And here is the full error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kung\Desktop\Autocompletion\Autocompletion.pyw", line 110, in changed
    self.manage_auto(matches)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'matches' referenced before assignment

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kung\Desktop\Autocompletion\Autocompletion.pyw", line 151, in <module>
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1120, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1537, in __call__
    self.widget._report_exception()
AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute '_report_exception'
```

Comment: please show the whole error.

Comment: There are problems with the indentation. When I try to run your code I get indentation errors. I had to fix four or five, and I have no idea if I indented or unindented the problem lines correctly.

Comment: By all means get rid of the harmfull "exception handler" around `root.mainloop()`,  it  prevents you from getting the full traceback which contains a lot of usefull informations about what when wrong and __where__ it went wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the initial code pasted, it was my first time pasting code on stack overflow. Just redo the pasting and this one should work. Also added the entire error output.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Thanks for the tip about removing the exception handler

Comment: @RyanKung you're welcome ;) - FWIW, the first rule about exception handling in Python is: unless you can _effectively_ handle an exception, just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what and where the problem is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Kung\Desktop\Autocompletion\Autocompletion.pyw", line 110, in changed
    self.manage_auto(matches)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'matches' referenced before assignment
```

The problem is this block of code:

```
if len(typed) > 0:
    matches = self.regex_match(typed)


# Manage autocompletion list box

self.manage_auto(matches)
```

If the entry field is empty, `matches` is not set. When you get to the next line you are trying to use `matches`. You need to set a default value for `matches` for the case where `len(typed)` is zero.

Comment: Thanks! Just realised the problem a second ago. So I defined matches by adding a line  matches = [] at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @RyanKung: please make sure you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers